# How to fix RPC error IncompatibleRemoteServiceException in a multi-project GWT setup?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I've decided to split my client server gwt project into 3 separate mvn projects:

- client
- server
- shared

the shared component contains all the model classes, Service interfaces, and ServiceAsync interfaces. This project is declared as dependency for both server and client gwt projects. Everything compiles fine, and the client application runs correctly.
The client also makes the correct rpc request, but server responds with:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException/3936916533","Type name elision in RPC payloads is only supported if the RPC whitelist file is used."
```

What can the problem be? should I configure something differently in my servlet implementation?

Comment: How do you run (and/or package and/or deploy) your app(s)?

Comment: I use maven for package/deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for whatever reason, your `*.gwt.rpc` files could not be loaded (i.e. they're either not present or perhaps not accessible through their expected URL). This probably means that you've got their location wrong after the split.

The error your receive is only present in a class called `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.LegacySerializationPolicy` which gets loaded if something happens with the regular policy files.
From the javadoc:

> A serialization policy compatible with GWT 1.3.3 RPC. This is used
>   when no serialization policy file is present.

In the same class, we have:

```
  private static final String ELISION_ERROR = "Type name elision in RPC "
      + "payloads is only supported if the RPC whitelist file is used.";
```

...and also stuff like:

```
  /**
   * Implemented to fail with a useful error message.
   */
  public final String getClassNameForTypeId(String id)
      throws SerializationException {
    throw new SerializationException(ELISION_ERROR);
  }
```

So it looks like this is deliberate, although the error message is ironically not very useful.

You can run a debugger through `RemoteServiceServlet#loadSerializationPolicy` and see why its not loading the policy files you expect it to.

Comment: you're right, i'm missing the policy files (.rpc). they exist in my server project, but not on the client side. what's the usual way of handling this? regenerate on the client project using web.xml or somehow reuse the ones from server?

Comment: I for one make sure to place them at the proper place during packaging. I do not know if you can generate them separately. But what's the issue, do you deploy your client/server modules on different servers?

Comment: as i mentioned above the client and the server are two completely separate projects/repositories, therefor built separately. although all the models and services are in yet another project which is marked as a mvn/gwt dependency for both client and serverside.

Comment: It doesn't matter how they're built, it matters how they are deployed. I build my modules separately too, but deploy them on the same server, and therefore I only need one set of serialization policies. 
Please be aware that server-side RPC loads resources via _servlet.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(
          serializationPolicyFilePath)_  .
Also, expect some troubles if you're using an apache front over a tomcat for example, and the public URL is different than tomcat's.

Comment: I did some testing, it turns out the only thing which is hindering it from working, is the url which is in the RPC payload... `7|1|4|https://url.foo/bar|2A094F8DDEB|_|getClientConfigData|1|2|3|4|0|`. i changed to the one is used by the original client (before separating backend/frontend) and eveything works. I have to find a way to do that in the new client. (if any of that made sens)

Comment: As I've stated above, you will run into trouble if the root context in your public URL of your app (i.e. example.com/foo) is different than what your container knows (for example when you map the internal name of your app, to a public name via apache).
I suspect something similar happens to you. Yes, you can do that by manipulating the RPC request.

Comment: RPC does some testing (some piece of info from RPC needs to match the server-side URL of the policy files) server side as some sort of security / anti-hijack feature. That's why some URLs have to match although it doesn't make much sense for the end user. The quickest way to find what's happening is to debug through the above-mentioned method.

Answer (score 0):

May be the browser is caching the .nochache.js files.

EDIT:

I just remember a time this happened. This is a vague memory... Is the servlet on the correct path? is the client requesting the correct url?

Services for module ModA looks in deploy/ModA/rpcPolicyManifest/manifests. Servlets should be mapped to /ModA/service, Clients must request to http://example.com/webapp/ModA/service.

Comment: made sure, no caching involved.